# energy/power signals

Tags: signal-processing

I have the two signals and need to determine whether they are energy type or power type:
$$x_1(t)=A\cos(2\pi ft), -\infty<t<\infty$$
$$x_2(t)=1$$

I have solved the first one using the expression for the energy of the signal and found that energy is infinite so it must be a power signal.
For the second one I don't know how to solve that as I don't know what limits to use.$$$$Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If no limits are given, I would assume plus/minus infinity as well. Or zero to infinity since it's about time....But it won't change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write the energy integral for the second signal in the same way you did for the first.

You'll see that it is a power signal too, since its energy is infinite:

$$
E_2 = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{|x_2(t)|^2}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt
= \lim_{T \,\to\, +\infty} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2}dt= +\infty
$$

Comment: It looks like the only problem OP has is that no time range is given as for the first one.